# jQuery : smoothly change left position of the element inside of a infinite loop using setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout, infinite-loop, cleartimeout

I'm trying to build a very simple scroller, where the number if images are scrolling left infinitely. I'm doing it by cloning the main element containing number of thumbnails and appending it as sibling to the main container. The problem I have is the smoothness of the animation as I use jQuery's css() method to deduct 1px every 10ms within the setTimeout() function.

I have effectively 2 questions:

1. Is setTimeout with clearTimeout() the right way to loop infinitely
2. Is there an effective way of smoothing the animation using css() method? Would using animate() not overkill it?

The method with the loop:

```
scrollContainers : function() {

    var self = this;

    clearTimeout(self.timeout);

    self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {

        var firstContainerPosition = self.containers[0].position();
        var secondContainerPosition = self.containers[1].position();


        if (Math.abs(firstContainerPosition.left) > self.containerWidth) {

            $(self.containers[0]).css('left', self.containerWidth);

        } else {

            $(self.containers[0]).css({ left : firstContainerPosition.left - 1 });

        }

        if (Math.abs(secondContainerPosition.left) > self.containerWidth) {

            $(self.containers[1]).css({ 'left' : self.containerWidth });

        } else {

            $(self.containers[1]).css({ left : secondContainerPosition.left - 1 });

        }

        self.scrollContainers();

    }, 10);

},
```

Comment: hey please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174010/loop-functions-animate-css-rotation/22174181#22174181 
last answer has infinate rotation - timeout isnt needed, only animate + callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @JF it - I'm not sure how this would work with two containers that need to move at the same time - any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @Spencer Mark, added an answer with multiple div's being animated..

Answer (score 1):

As above comment - animating 2+ containers is fine, just add the selectors of the elements you want to move:

http://jsfiddle.net/QfeC2/12/
they will work fine together. doesnt seem to be any lag issues in ie too.

```
var boolDirection = true;

function AnimateRotate(angle) {
// caching the object for performance reasons
var $elem = $('div');

// we use a pseudo object for the animation
// (starts from `0` to `angle`), you can name it as you want
$({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function(now) {
        // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
        // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
        // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
        $elem.css({
            transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'
        });
    },
    complete: function(){
        if(boolDirection)
        {
        AnimateRotate(-360);
            boolDirection = false;
        }
        else
        {
            AnimateRotate(360);
            boolDirection=true;
        }
    }
});
} 
AnimateRotate(360);
```

Comment: you can animate any style/movement.. see https://api.jquery.com/animate/ also, effects tab may work for you if you want to get fancy.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) For animation better is to use requestAnimationFrame than timeouts. You could read more about it here http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

ad 2) Best way to animate position is by doing it by translate rather that left property - more on Paul Irish blog http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/